# Is there a function to find number of transactions?

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, counting, symbolic-math

I have Google Sheets where I summarize my spendings based on categories.

For example "Online shopping" - `=100+52+35+841`

We can agree on there being 4 terms in this formula. That symbolize that I've made 4 transactions.

Ex.2 `=18+45+124+1045-16`

I got 16 back (maybe I made a part-return or got paid for something)
This time it is 5 terms/transactions.

With the LEN + SUBSTITUTE function Google can "count" the amount of integers in that cell.

In ex. 2 that would return 13. (1,8,4,5...)

I want to count every term in the summery. So that the return is 5 for ex. 2 and 4 for example 1.

When that is possible it should be possible to count the amount of numbers with decimal representation. I.e. `=25,45+109,05-34,5` should result in 3 transactions.

Also `=12` should result in 1 transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/LEN(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A, "[0-9\.,=]", )))+1))
```

[image]

---

### update 1:

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/LEN(REGEXREPLACE(FORMULATEXT(A15), "["" a-z0-9\.,=]", )))+1)
```

[image]

### update 2:

```
=IF(A1="",,LEN(REGEXREPLACE(FORMULATEXT(A1), "["" 0-9\.,=]", ))+1)
```

[image]

Comment: I think you need to `+1` at the end: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A="", "", INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/LEN(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A, "[0-9\.,]", )))) + 1) ))` but then wrap it with an `arrayformula` for the column.

Comment: @Ihopethisishelpfultoyou indeed. gratitude

Comment: What about if the cell is "=25,45+109,05-34,5" and not only "25,45+109,05-34,5"?

Comment: @OskyEdzSnakehult sure, answer updated

Comment: @player0 are you using Google sheets or MS excel? If I do "2+3+4" the formula return 3. But if I do "=2+3+4" I get nothing. The cell returned blank.

Comment: @OskyEdzSnakehult https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14xx7si0rZAxGf633DzMhngJsNjvHbLaX_U_EVHdRSbg/edit#gid=0

Comment: @player0 yeah, your using '= and ="=...." to avoid my problem.
I still want to summarize the numbers and also know how many they are.

Comment: @OskyEdzSnakehult I see... answer updated

Comment: Well it works, almost all of the time. It does not handle single values, but it should. When broken down the each component...

Comment: @OskyEdzSnakehult answer updated

Answer (score 0):

If the only transactions are `+` or `-`, it's just the count of those symbols plus one.

Suppose your original strings were in A2:A. Place the following in B2 of an an otherwise empty B2:B (or in the Row-2 cell of any other open column):

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,LEN(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A,"[^+-]",""))+1))`

This one formula will process all entries in the range A2:A.

If you just want to process one cell instead of a contiguous range, you can use this formula, replacing `A2` with your individual cell reference:

`=LEN(REGEXREPLACE(A2,"[^+-]",""))+1`

Either formula is just using REGEX to replace every character *except* `+` or `-` and then returning the `LEN`gth of the remaining string plus one.

Comment: Your post shows the starting data as a string that contains the equals sign (e.g., "=100+52+35+841"). Even in your comment above, you've placed everything including the equals sign in quote (i.e., "=25,45+109,05-34,5").  If your actual data is other than what you show in your post and comments, there is no way we could know this. I also don't understand your comment about "semicolon instead of colon," since none of my formulas use a colon. In some locales, Google Sheets uses a semicolon in place of a *comma*; is that what you mean? (Again, we don't know your locale, so we write to our own.)

Comment: I should've used `=25,45+109,05-34,5`...
Sorry about the locale stuff.

Comment: It sounds like you're wanting to extract from *live formulas*. Just wrap the references in my formulas in `FORMULATEXT( )` (e.g., for a value in A1 ... `=LEN(REGEXREPLACE(FORMULATEXT(A1),"[^+-]",""))+1`). But it looks like you came to a solution that works for you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I found a custom solution based on @player0 answer, help and comments!

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/(1+LEN(REGEXREPLACE(FORMULATEXT(A1), "["" 0-9\.,=]", )))))
```

The `1+LEN()` (instead of `1/(1/LEN())+1`) is required to solve the problem where I only had one value. i.e. `=25` to return 1 instead of nothing.